# How to prove the existence of infinite geodesics that do not intersect in hyperbolic space

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

My given question is:

In hyperbolic space, given a geodesic $L$ and a point $p$ not lying on $L$, show there is an infinite number of geodesics through $p$ which do not intersect $L$.

The "model" for hyperbolic space is the upper half plane $H=\{(x,y):y>0\}$ where in this model, distance decreases as we move up. In this way, I can understand how it's true in my head, but I'm not sure how to start to prove this.

Where is a good place to start proving this?

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of a possible approach:

- Show (or know) that a geodesic in the hyperbolic space is the equivalent in the the upper half plane model of a vertical ray or of a semicircle centred on the $x$-axis
- Consider the three possibilities that $L$ is a vertical ray with $p$ not on $L$, or $L$ is a semicircle with $p$ "inside" the semicircle, or  $L$ is a semicircle with $p$ "outside" the semicircle
- For each possibility, show there is an interval  on the $x$-axis where all semi-circles centred on that interval and passing through $p$ do not intersect $L$
- Draw your conclusion